# Load Wordpress specific post template from ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a template `portfolio-modal.php` that builds the html for a post's modal window.

I can load the php template from `functions.php`

```
function ajaxPortfolioItem(){  
  //get the data from ajax() call  
   $postID = $_GET['postID'];  
   $portfolioItem = get_template_part('portfolio','modal');
   die($portfolioItem);  
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxPortfolioItem', 'ajaxPortfolioItem' );
```

But how can I pass the `$postID` to the template, so it can render the right post?

This seems like something I've seen a million themes do, but I've searched all over and can't find an answer.

P.S. I'm not a WP guy, so maybe I'm approaching this wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a theme I'm working on now I'm loading a specific page on click event with this

```
$(".YourOpeningButton").click(function(){
        var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#YourContainer").html("loading...");
        $("#YourContainer").load(post_link + " #container > * ");
    return false;
    });
```

Then you just have to create a page in WP, and add a link to this page in your theme.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/YourPage/" class="">link</a>
```

When you click `YourOpeningButton` it should check the href and open this page in `YourContainer`. I hope it helps...

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that you can just access any php file from the address bar.  Super simple, thanks.